# Perl \R regex strip Windows newline character

Tags: regex, linux, windows, perl, newline

I'm using a Perl script using the following code to remove possible Windows newline characters in input file:

`foreach my $line(split /\r|\R/)`

Executing the same script on two different Linux machines has different results. On machine1 script works as intended, on machine2 every time a capital "R" character is found line is split and result is messed.

I would like to know if the `\R` regex is correct and how to make machine2 behave as intended.

Comment: you should not have to look for `\R`

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: @Shane_Yo, What are you talking about? `\R` is exactly the right tool if his Perl was new enough.

Answer (score 7):

In Perl, there are several differences in the way carriage returns can be handled:

```
\n matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
\r matches a carriage return (ASCII 13)
\R matches any Unicode newline sequence; can be modified using verbs
```

Windows uses the two characters `ASCII 13`+`ASCII 10` (`\r\n`) and unix uses `ASCII 10` (`\n`). The `\R` expression matches any Unicode newline sequence (`\r`, `\n`, `\r\n`).

The likely reason `\R` works on one machine and not the other might be differing versions of `Perl`. `\R` was introduced in `perl 5.10.0`, so if the other machine is using an older version then updating should solve your issue.

**More info**:

- [Perl Regular Expression Backslash Sequences and Escapes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Misc)
- [Syntax of Regular Expressions in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: I am running ActiveState Perl 5.24.3 on Windows, and I get a `Unrecognized escape \R in character class passed through in regex` error when I use `\R` in a regex.

Comment: @pacoverflow, In Perl `\R` won't work inside a character class, try using `\v` instead (see: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass).

Answer (score 3):

One of your machines must be using a rather ancient version of Perl.

5.8:

```
$ perl -wle'print for split /\R/, "QRS\r\nTUV\r\n";'
Unrecognized escape \R passed through at -e line 1.
Q
S
TUV
```

5.10:

```
$ perl -wle'print for split /\R/, "QRS\r\nTUV\r\n";'
QRS
TUV
```

Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

Alternatives:

- `split /[\r\n]/`. This is equivalent to what you are using, but it's probably buggy.
- `split /\n|\r\n?/`. This is equivalent to `split /\R/`.
- `split /\r?\n/`. This matches unix and Windows line endings.
- `split /\r\n/`. This matches Windows line endings.

I'd use the second last.

Comment: I am running ActiveState Perl 5.24.3 on Windows, and I get a `Unrecognized escape \R in character class passed through in regex` error when I use `\R` in a regex.

Comment: @pacoverflow, `\R` doesn't map to a character. It can't be used in a character class (`[]`)

Answer (score 0):

I use Perl nearly every day.

However, if all I have to do is convert line endings, then I use

- [`dos2unix`](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man%5Fpages/dos2unix1.html) to convert to Linux/Unix line endings
- [`unix2dos`](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/unix2dos1.html) to convert to Windows line endings.